# How to change the time of Maintance Activity in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

My First question why elasticsearch run maintenance activity automatically

I'm unable to track what time this occurs by this time I'm unable to pull the record.

Can we change this timing? Below shared my logs. The status changing from Red to Yellow is it correct and can we change it to GREEN

Kindly somebody can give your inputs and view on it.

Thanks in Advance.

```
[2018-12-09T15:24:41,022][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [_7EG38y] started
[2018-12-09T15:24:42,005][WARN ][o.e.x.s.a.s.m.NativeRoleMappingStore] [_7EG38y]
 Failed to clear cache for realms [[]]
[2018-12-09T15:24:42,083][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [_7EG38y] license [8
ec47b44-ca97-42ca-8836-df541be12e06] mode [basic] - valid
[2018-12-09T15:24:42,099][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [_7EG38y] recovered
[1] indices into cluster_state
[2018-12-09T15:24:43,487][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [_7EG38y] Cluster
health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[data]
[0]] ...]).
[2018-12-10T00:48:00,430][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] triggering s
cheduled [ML] maintenance tasks
[2018-12-10T00:48:01,413][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [_7
EG38y] Deleting expired data
[2018-12-10T00:48:03,628][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [_7
EG38y] Completed deletion of expired data
[2018-12-10T00:48:03,643][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] Successfully
 completed [ML] maintenance tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ML scheduled maintenance activity. Not sure if it can be modified, try checking scheduled events under ML in Kibana. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/scheduled-events-and-the-amorous-anomaly-elasticsearch-machine-learning) link for more info.